# multiple values in select reactJS

Tags: reactjs, select

i need to retrieve the region price and region id got from API from a single select component. I cant figure out how to get this done. any help would be so appreciated. thank you

```
{"message":"success","data":[{"id":1,"name":"JABODETABEK","description":"daerah sekitar jabodetabek","additional_price":1000,"createdAt":"2022-10-04T10:35:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2022-10-04T10:35:16.000Z"},{"id":2,"name":"JAWA BARAT","description":"bagian jawa barat","additional_price":500,"createdAt":"2022-10-12T09:24:47.000Z","updatedAt":"2022-10-12T09:24:47.000Z"}]}
```

`

```
<select id='regionList' key={regionId} onChange={handleChange2}>
                <option >Select Your Region</option>
                {region?.data.map(reg => (
                          <option value={[reg.additional_price, reg.id]} key={reg.id}>{reg.name}</option>
                        ))
                        }
```

`

this is my code so far

Comment: Can you write the API code as well

Comment: @AhmedGaafer i added the API json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you save the value

you need to split it because it is casted to a string

here is a react sandbox example

https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-over-flow-2-0w51kc?file=/src/App.js